# Retrieving field metadata from the result of a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve the result of a complex query from a MySQL DB implementing a serverside method (API programmed with php+CodeIgniter) that will allow configuration options (sent by the clientside) such as tables, related fields, join type etc.

I also need to retrieve the metadata -data types and constraints- of each column returned by the query in order to configure and load a clientside editable grid (javascript+extjs).

For this last part i was thinking about creating a temporary VIEW from the generated query so i could easly query 'TABLES' and 'VIEWS' from 'information_schema' to retrieve the metadata.

My first though was to directly query the 'COLUMNS' table from 'information_schema' for each field that is included in the query result, but i think this cant be done since i cant know the 'parent table' for each of the columns from the query result. (im right?)

So. Are my assumptions correct? Is there a clean way (or at least working way) to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the database client library you're using, those normally provide meta-information about the columns in the resultset as well. Consult the manual for your client library. See as well the related questions on the right what is and what is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
desc table
```

-store it in an array or table or whatever

-work with the data

this is the most primitive way and always work with me

Comment: by the way i use codeiginiter too that's why i had to do that :)